# LTTNG: using with a popular library

Tags: c++, linux, lttng

I have a trivially simple question that I could not find the answer yet.

Say, I have a shared library X that is used by 100 simultaneously running applications A0, A1, ... A99. I had instrumented my library and with LTTNG using "X-Provider" as the provider name.  How can my user distinguish between X-Provider events that happen in A10 and A15?

Comment: I've this question a few times over the last day. Was it a class assignment to bother the people here?

Comment: No just practical development of a large system slowly converting to lttng. Can you answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `lttng` command-line utility, add the `vpid` context field to be recorded to your event records, for example:

```
$ lttng add-context -u -t vpid
```

This targets all the user space channels of the current recording session; you can of course select a specific recording session and/or channel (see [lttng-add-context(1)](https://lttng.org/man/1/lttng-add-context/v2.13/)).

You need to use this command before you start the tracers (`lttng start`).

All your event records will have a context field named `vpid` which is the virtual IDs of the processes which emitted them.

Now, you need to find a way to associate such VPIDs to instance IDs (A10, A15, etc.). You can do so with your own application-specific strategy, or you can simply record an initial event when starting the application which indicates the instance ID/name, for example:

```
tracepoint(x_provider, app_state, app_id);
```

Then, when reading the resulting trace(s), you can correlate the `x_provider:app_state` event record info with the records of your library-emitted events. For example, using the [Babeltrace 2 Python bindings](https://babeltrace.org/docs/v2.0/python/bt2/):

```
import bt2

vpid_app_ids = {}

for msg in bt2.TraceCollectionMessageIterator('/path/to/trace'):
    if type(msg) is not bt2._EventMessageConst:
        continue

    vpid = int(msg.event.common_context_field['vpid'])

    if msg.event.name == 'x_provider:app_state':
        app_id = int(msg.event.payload_field['app_id'])
        vpid_app_ids[vpid] = app_id
    else:
        app_id = vpid_app_ids[vpid]

        # Continue to process `msg.event` knowing the instance ID is
        # `app_id`...
```

I didn't test the example above, but you get the gist.

Comment: Thank you. It does not seem straightforward though. I suppose we have to invent some common initialization to handle multiple libraries per process transparently. I had hope that it will be possible for a library to get hold of the process main provider and install/register self as sort of sub-provider :(

Comment: For more advanced use cases, please write to the [lttng-dev](https://lists.lttng.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/lttng-dev) mailing list. Given enough context, you'll find more LTTng help there.